# What is the MapReduce application master?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

From Hadoop The Definitive Guide

> [image]
>
> The whole process is illustrated in Figure 7-1. At the highest level,
>   there are five independent entities:
>
> • The client, which submits the MapReduce job.
>
> • The YARN resource manager, which coordinates the allocation of
>   compute re‐ sources on the cluster.
>
> • The YARN node managers, which launch and monitor the compute
>   containers on machines in the cluster.
>
> • The MapReduce application master, which coordinates the tasks
>   running the Map‐ Reduce job. The application master and the MapReduce
>   tasks run in containers that are scheduled by the resource manager and
>   managed by the node managers.

What is the MapReduce application master?

In a MapReduce program written in Java, we need three things: a map function, a reduce function, and some code with `main()` function to run the job. Is  the MapReduce application master the code with `main()` function to run a map reduce job?

Answer (score 2):

`main()` function in typical Hadoop program usually does these things:

- specifies the input/output path for the job
- configures mappers/reducers/combiners/partitioners
- configures memory

Then it creates an instance of `Job` interface, runs it and calls `waitForCompletion`, which blocks until job is finished. This call sends Yarn application request under the hood, which spawns AppMaster somewhere on the cluster.

AppMaster is responsible for creating Map/Reduce processes, tracking their status and reporting the progress. There's 1 instance of AppMaster for every job running on Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Thanks.  Is the MapReduce application master the code with main() function to run a map reduce job?

Comment: @Tim sorry if I was unclear, but again, your main() function is used only for configuration and submitting a job. AppMaster coordinates job execution on distributed cluster. AppMaster will uses Mapper and Reducer classes provided by you, and they will process the data